# how to add slide menu close button on navigationbar

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I have implemented the slide menu it has a close button but the close button goes under the navigation bar. How it brings it above the navigation bar and slide as menu slider.
Here is how I want the close button.

[image]

Comment: add menu in window instead of view : self.view.window.addSubview( menuView) .

Comment: instead of adding menuview to your self.view. add in to window and use bring subview to front method to get the full view.

Comment: I have tried this but not working. I was unable to close the slide menu.
Right now I am adding this like self.addChildViewController(menuVC)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
window.addSubview(menuView)
window?.bringSubview(toFront: menuView)
```